# How can I fire the ShareThis popup window using jQuery?

Tags: sharethis

The ShareThis code we are using activates the popup window based on hovering over the email button (.st_email), but I can't seem to get the popup to activate automatically using jQuery.

I've tried..

```
$(".st_email").mouseover();
$(".st_email").click();
```

Any ideas?

Here is the embedded ShareThis code:

```
<!-- ShareThis Code -->
<script type="text/javascript">var switchTo5x=true;</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">stLight.options({publisher: "########"}); </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">stLight.options({publisher: "########",onhover: false}); </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example assumes that you have an element with the *class* st_email (that's what the . in front of st_email means).

That selector will *select* that element, but you have to *do* something in the event handler:

```
$(".st_email").mouseover(function(e) { /* Write code to show your popup */ });
```

I can't fill in the commented piece without knowing more about your popup.

If you do this with *mouseover*, you need to correctly handle the possibility of receiving multiple *mouseover* events.

Handling with *click* is easier in that regard, if that is acceptable in your case.  Here's code that shows how do react to the click event:

```
$(".st_email").click(function(e) { alert('put code here to open popup'); });
```

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough.  My goal is to make the existing ShareThis popup automatically open on page load, not create my own popup in addition to that.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to click the div inside shareThis button container:

- $(".st_email > div").mouseover();
- $(".st_email > div").click();